Sitecore 10.4 Multiple Identifier for Contact
I am working on Sitecore 10.4 and I have below requirement.

I have form where identifier is email.
I have one login portal where identifier will be the username.

Also I am saving some custom facets.
So my requirement is that if user fill detail in form then go to the portal after login then both interaction should be merge into one contact also the facets. Same if user login into portal then go to form then contact should be the same.
It is also possible that user login into portal from some device so it will create one contact then from other device, user fill form and then login into portal so in this case also contact must be the same.
Please help me.

As you have mentioned there is no relation between the two identifier so you can follow the below steps:

Once the user submits the form, you can create a contact or update other details in contact facets if an identifier already exists.
On the login portal you can check if contact already has an identifier or not, using the code below:

var formIdentifier = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact?.Identifiers?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Source == 'emailIdentifier')?.Identifier;


Then you create a new contact for login or update if the username identifier exists.
After this one you check if the form identifier exists or not, if it exists then you can merge these two contacts:

client.MergeContacts(formIdentifier , loginContact);


Same thing you can do in form code.

You can use merge contact feature in xDB to merge contacts from different sources. There can be two identifiers created for contact, one using loginportal as a source and other using the form as a source.
In the below code snippet, when the user logins from the login portal, a contact identifier with the source as loginportal is added. Then xDB is queried to get the existing contact with the form as the source identifier. If there is an existing contact with the form source identifier containing the user email address, then both these contact are merged in xDB
using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient()){
  
  // New known contact
  var identifers = new ContactIdentifier[] { new ContactIdentifier("loginportal", "username", ContactIdentifierType.Known) };
  var newContact = new Contact(identifers);
  client.AddContact(newContact);

  // Contact must be saved before a merge
  client.Submit();

  // Reference to existing contact
  var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference("form", "email");
  Contact existingContact = client.Get<Contact>(reference, new ContactExecutionOptions(new ContactExpandOptions() { }));

  // Data copied FROM existingContact TO newContact
  if(existingContact != null){
    client.MergeContacts(existingContact, newContact);
    client.Submit();
  }
}

When the contacts are merged, all known identifiers are moved from the source contact to the target contact.
More details on the merging rules in xDB can be found here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-platform/merge-contacts.html
Note: You must create a calculated facet merge handler for calculated facets, as they may required custom merge logic. Value facets are merged automatically.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-facet-merge-handler.html#implement-a-merge-handler
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

Once user login into loginportal then we are not saving identifier in session and at the time when user fill the form then it will not have loginportal identifier.

@JohnDavies Is there any api that associates email and username..There need to be some assocation between both of them to map them with the contact in xDB.
